# Gregorian Calendar: Getting a user's (day_of_the_week) from their own birthday input

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I'm a VERY amateur coder who can't seem to wrap his head around a problem with getting a day of the week (e.g. Sunday, Monday, etc.) from user inputted integers. I'm just trying to give a user a message which lays out (mm/dd/yyyy, dayOfWeek), but instead of a changing day of week, I keep getting Wednesday as a day of week answer, no matter what I put inside the prompt box. I just need a new direction to head into. Any mistakes with my code or an avenue I'm not seeing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String returnValue = "";
        int month2=0;
        int day2=0;
        int year2=0;
        GregorianCalendar userbirthday = new GregorianCalendar(year2, month2, day2);
        int userweekday=userbirthday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);




        String usermonth;
        System.out.print ("What month is your birthday?");
        usermonth = user_input.next();

        String userday;
        System.out.print ("What day is your birthday?");
        userday = user_input.next();

        String useryear;
        System.out.print ("What year was your birth?");
        useryear = user_input.next();

        year2 = Integer.parseInt(useryear);
        month2 = Integer.parseInt(usermonth);
        day2 = Integer.parseInt(userday);


        String dayOfTheWeek = "";

        if(month2 == 0){
        System.out.println("That's not a valid birthday! Check your month.");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (month2>=13){
       System.out.println("That's not a valid birthday! Check your month.");
       System.exit(0);
    }
        if(day2 == 0){
        System.out.println("That's not a valid birthday! Check your day.");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (day2>=32){
       System.out.println("That's not a valid birthday! Check your day."); 
       System.exit(0);
    }
         if(userweekday == 2){
         dayOfTheWeek= "Mon";           
    } else if (userweekday==3){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Tue";
    } else if (userweekday==4){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Wed";
    } else if (userweekday==5){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Thu";
    } else if (userweekday==6){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Fri";
    } else if (userweekday==7){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Sat";
    } else if (userweekday==1){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Sun";
    }

        String birthdate = month2 + "/" + day2 + "/" + year2 + "," + dayOfTheWeek;



        System.out.println ("Your birthday was" + " " + birthdate);

 }
```

Comment: `userbirthday = new GregorianCalendar(year2, month2, day2)` ... you are initialising the userbirthday with 0,0,0, which probably was a wednesday.

Comment: Don't use GregorianCalendar. It's an awfully designed class, that's been superseded by classes of the java.time package. Use that (a LocalDate is probably all you need).

Answer (score 4):

You are doing things in the wrong order. As your code in the question stands the following is what happened:

1. You are initializing `month2`, `day2` and `year2` to 0.
2. You are creating your `GregorianCalendar` object from those variables having the value of 0. This gives you Wednesday, December 31 year 2 BCE (there is no year 0, so you are setting to 0th of January year 1 BCE, which equals December 31 year 2 BCE — confusing, but for a `GregorianCalendar` it’s the truth). Then you take the day of week out into `userweekday` (always equal to `Calendar.WEDNESDAY`).
3. Finally in the lines `year2 = Integer.parseInt(useryear);`, etc., you are assigning the user input to the variables. This does not affect the `GregorianCalendar` object you have already created nor the day of week already got from that `GregorianCalendar`.

Therefore Wednesday will always be printed.

As an aside, the `GregorianCalendar` class is long outdated and has design problems. Among other issues it often requires verbose code which can also be error-prone. And it numbers months in an unexpected way. Instead I suggest you use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
LocalDate              // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone. 
.of( y , m , d )       // Specify year-month-day, 1-12 for January-December. 
.getDayOfWeek()        // Extract a `DayOfWeek` enum object representing one of seven days of the week. 
.getDisplayName(       // Automatically localize the text of the name of the day of the week. 
    TextStyle.SHORT ,  // Specify how long or abbreviated. 
    Locale.US          // Locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in localizing. 
)
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Thank you for the first two pieces of advice, I changed the code so that  (int year= userbirthday.get(Calendar.YEAR);), etc., but I don't think I understand the third piece of advice. How would I assign the variables that I want to use with what the user enters in the Scanner?

Comment: @AnfanioluwaLawal If I understand your question correctly: Your assignment of user input to the variables is correct. Only you need to do that (and the following validation) *before* creating your `GregorianCalendar` object. Or still better, before creating your `LocalDate` object (as shown at the bottom of my answer, the kind edit by Basil Bourque).